# Python: Closest Point to a line

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, shapely

I have the following question. I have a box full of coordinates and three points, which build up a line. Now i want to calculate the shortest distance of all box coordinates to that line. I have three methods to do that and the vtk and numpy version always have the same result but not the distance method of shapely. But i need the shapely version, because i want to measure the closest distance from a point to the whole line and not to the separate line segments. Here is an example code so far. So the problem is the "pdist":

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
import vtk, numpy as np
import itertools

import math

from numpy.linalg import norm

x1=np.arange(4,21)
y1=np.arange(4,21)
z1=np.arange(-7,6)

linepoints = np.array([[1,10,0],[10,10,0],[15,15,0]])


for i in itertools.product(x1,y1,z1):
    
    for m in range(len(linepoints)-1):
        
        line3 = LineString([linepoints[m],linepoints[m+1]])
        
        p = Point(i)
        
        d = norm(np.cross(linepoints[m]-linepoints[m+1], linepoints[m]-i))/norm(linepoints[m+1]-linepoints[m])
        
        dist=math.sqrt(vtk.vtkLine().DistanceToLine(i,linepoints[m],linepoints[m+1]))
        
        pdist = p.distance(line3)
        
        print(d,dist,pdist)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that with cross-product you are calculating orthogonal distance to the line spanned by the segment defined by points `linepoints[m]` and `linepoints[m+1]`. On the other hand, Shapely calculates distance to the segment, i.e., it returns the distance either to the orthogonal projection or to one of the boundary points should the orthogonal projection fall "outside" of the segment.

To get consistent results, you could calculate the orthogonal projection yourself and then invoke the Shapely distance method:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString


A = np.array([1,0])
B = np.array([3,0])
C = np.array([0,1])


l = LineString([A, B])
p = Point(C)


d = np.linalg.norm(np.cross(B - A, C - A))/np.linalg.norm(B - A)

n = B - A
v = C - A

z = A + n*(np.dot(v, n)/np.dot(n, n))

print(l.distance(p), d, Point(z).distance(p))
#1.4142135623730951 1.0 1.0
```

However, note that Shapely effectively ignores the z-coordinate. Thus for example:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

A = np.array([1,0,1])
B = np.array([0,0,0])

print(Point([1,0,1]).distance(Point([0,0,0])))
```

return as distance merely 1.

EDIT:
based on your comment, here would be a version which calculates the distance (for arbitrary number of dimensions) to the segment:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
import numpy as np
import itertools

import math

from numpy.linalg import norm

x1=np.arange(4,21)
y1=np.arange(4,21)
z1=np.arange(-7,6)

linepoints = np.array([[1,10,0],[10,10,0],[15,15,0]])

def dist(A, B, C):
    """Calculate the distance of point C to line segment spanned by points A, B.

    """

    a = np.asarray(A)
    b = np.asarray(B)
    c = np.asarray(C)

    #project c onto line spanned by a,b but consider the end points
    #should the projection fall "outside" of the segment    
    n, v = b - a, c - a

    #the projection q of c onto the infinite line defined by points a,b
    #can be parametrized as q = a + t*(b - a). In terms of dot-products,
    #the coefficient t is (c - a).(b - a)/( (b-a).(b-a) ). If we want
    #to restrict the "projected" point to belong to the finite segment
    #connecting points a and b, it's sufficient to "clip" it into
    #interval [0,1] - 0 corresponds to a, 1 corresponds to b.

    t = max(0, min(np.dot(v, n)/np.dot(n, n), 1))
    return np.linalg.norm(c - (a + t*n)) #or np.linalg.norm(v - t*n)


for coords in itertools.product(x1,y1,z1):
    for m in range(len(linepoints)-1):

        line3 = LineString([linepoints[m],linepoints[m+1]])
        d = dist(linepoints[m], linepoints[m+1], coords)
        print(coords, d)
```

Comment: Ah this is a problem! What would be then the best approach to calculate the closest distance of all 3D Points to a polyline? Because in some cases the points have the closest distance to the infinite extension of a linesegment, but i need the closest distance to a point on the segment/line and of course in z direction too. I think this is what you described with that orthogonal projection?

Comment: @Varlor I have update the answer with what I think would be a general method. In the `dist` function, the restriction of the parameter `t` into the interval `[0,1]` makes sure that it calculates the distance to the finite segment. Without this constraint, it would return distance to the infinite line...

Comment: Ah nice, it works. Can you explain what exactly hapens mathematically in the lines:

 n, v = b - a, c - a
t = max(0, min(np.dot(v, n)/np.dot(n, n), 1))
return np.linalg.norm(c - (a + t*n)) #or np.linalg.norm(v - t*n)

Comment: @Varlor I have included additional comments, in short, `t` defines the fraction of the line segment connecting `a` and `b` where the orthogonal projection of `c` is located.