# Orthogonal distance between a reference line and successive points of a polyline

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry, shapely

[image: Image showing reference line (red) and polyline (yellow)]

The image shows (1) a red line which I am calling my reference line, and (2) a yellow polyline. Each line feature consists of thousands of points of x,y coordinate pairs. I would like to incrementally move along the red reference line, and calculate the orthogonal distance (with respect to the red line) to each coordinate pair point of the yellow polyline. I am working in python 3.

Here are the first 25 coordinate pairs for the red reference line:

- [image]

Here are the first 25 coordinate pairs for the yellow polyline:

- [image: List item]

I have been trying a few approaches based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848406/distance-from-reference-line-at-right-angle), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861488/distance-between-two-polylines) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129007/python-closest-point-to-a-line). I am testing an answer discussed at the last [hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129007/python-closest-point-to-a-line) to try to build a workflow:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

x1 = 457508.40746964136
x2 = 457508.5456318401

y1 = 8872649.617776532
y2 = 8872649.773129418

dist = np.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)

centerX = (x2 - x1) / 2 + x1
centerY = (y2 - y1) / 2 + y1

test_x = centerX - dist/4
test_y = centerY + dist

line = LineString([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])  
print(list(line.coords))

p = Point(test_x,test_y)  
print(list(p.coords))

print(p.distance(line))
```

p.distance(line) returns: 0.17780...Here is an image of what this particular test looks like:

[image]

The black points are two successive coordinate pairs on the red reference line. The red point is a test coordinate pair to use to calculate the orthogonal distance from the black point to the light blue line segment. It seems to me the p.distance result given above is too short for the orthogonal distance. I would appreciate any help to make progress on this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming the red line is always a single straight line, you could transform the points such that the x axis becomes distance-along-line (i.e. all red y coordinates are 0), then you could just do linear interpolation ([see interp1d()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)) at each desired interval

Comment: @mikewatt so interpolate to what specific set of coordinates? Maybe my goal is not clear from my description above, or I do not see how to get there from your comment. Take the plot given above as an example. The goal is to project a line segment to the red dot, from the line segment in between the two black dots; the projected line must be orthogonal to the line segment connecting the two black dots. Then I want to calculate the distance of this projected line to the red dot. Then I would repeat the process moving along the red reference line, projecting to the yellow line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orthogonal distance from point `(test_x,test_y)` to line `(x1,y1)-(x2,y2)` might be calculated with vector algebra

```
orthodistance = abs((y2 - y1)*test_x - (x2 - x1)*test_y + x2*y1 - y2*x1) / dist)
```

and this expression gives `0.176` for your data, so result looks close.

Note that your image scale is not perfect - plot is **stretched in X-direction**, that is why you might doubt.

Comment: MBo indeed it looks like you are correct. Here is a link to an updated plot with the axes plotted to the same scale: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igPQS.png). I have added one more coordinate pair to the reference line since the projected point (dark blue point) on the reference line plotted to the right of the line segment as originally shown. Thanks for the vector algebra solution, and your help.